# Scala: assigning a string variable a value

Tags: string, scala

Scala doesn't seem to like me assigning values to a String val. I get errors whenever I try:

```
val s = new String
s = "hi"
```

Comment: You should really consider reading some of the basics of Scala. A good entry-point might be this: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/25

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `val` is final, you cannot reassign it.

```
val s = "hi"
```

This works (but why would you do that ?)

```
var s = new String
s = "hi"
```

(edit)
do this instead

```
var s = "hi"
```

Scala infers types; you do not need to specify String in this case

Comment: Oh, what should I label it then? I'm sorry I'm literally starting to learn Scala.

Comment: `var s = "hi"` or `val s = "hi"` depending on what you want to do later with `s`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much! Oh I'm just learning Scala and rebuilding some of my python scripts in Scala... thought that would be a good way to learn the language.

Comment: Sacla infers types; you do not need to specify `String` in this case. Good luck with you rewriting

Comment: @BGR is correct, however you sometimes need to explicitly specify field type after a colon to avoid using concrete implementations, like so: `val service: Service = new ServiceImpl`

Comment: @Sergey +1 - as with anything magic like type inference, you do not always want the magic to happen. As another example, I personally always specify the type of non trivial functions in their definitions to facilitate maintenance and better express intent.

Answer (score 4):

`val s = "hi"`

is all you need. If you want to be explicit about the type, go for

`val s: String = "hi"`